# TransitionAnimation shows both on top of each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am trying to use a TransitionAnimation to switch between two background images.

Here's the main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/screen"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MyActivity"
  tools:deviceIds="wear_round"
  android:background="@drawable/background">
</RelativeLayout>
```

As You can see, the background is called "background". It's code is following:

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/start_background"/>
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/pause_background"/>
</transition>
```

start_background and pause_background are two different images, one representing something like a "play" button and the other one a "pause" button.

Now I call the transition like that:

```
private TransitionAnimation transition;
private RelativeLayout screen;

screen = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.screen);
transition = (TransitionDrawable)screen.getBackground();
```

Now when pressing the screen, following method gets called:

```
transition.startTransition(100);
```

Or

```
transition.reverseTransition(100);
```

Now the problem is, when pressing the screen, the background image switches between

[image]

And

[image]

As You can see, the first image contains the play **and** the pause button on top of each other, probably there are two play images on top of each other on the second image as well.

I don't know how that comes, any suggestions?

Here are the two background files:

pause_background.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pause_background_pressed"/>

  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/pause_background_default"/>
</selector>
```

start_background.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/start_background_pressed"/>

  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/start_background_default"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just setting the background to `start_background_pressed` at the start in background.xml at the start is what you need.  By just setting it as a transition in the layout file it probably isn't smart enough to handle it.  Both probably get drawn.

Then you can set the transition in the code when it is first interacted with.  I would assume it would work as expected from that point on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work, still the same problem. start_background_pressed is just an darker image which appears when the view gets touched.

Comment: If it's darker, then you are probably right, it is drawing twice over the area.  Not sure as to why it would, I'll look further into it.  I have had double draws when not expecting in certain circumstances.